# Spring Freemarker Form Bind : Problem with Exponent Value

Tags: spring, freemarker

I have `Spring` bind  form with `freemarker`. But large number show `Exponent` value. How to show value without `Exponent`.

**For small numeber**...

```
 <@spring.formInput 'CaseMaster.year' 'placeholder="e.g. 2013" ' 'number'/>
```

**For large number**...

```
<@spring.formInput 'CaseMaster.suitValue' 'placeholder="e.g. Suit Value" ' />
```

**HTML View:**

[image]

I wnat to show value like `80000000` or `80000000.00` or like `8,00,00,000.00` in the second field.

Comment: Why is the type `'number'` for small numbers, but not for large?

Comment: @CharlesForsythe `'number'` is not an issue. If I put number for the large, output remains same.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect that your issue is that the value is a `BigDecimal`. `BigDecimal,toString()` will do this kind of formatting. `BigDecimal.toPlainString()` will just give you a number. What is the type of `CaseMaster.suitValue`?

Comment: @CharlesForsythe, Its `java.lang.Double`.

Answer (score 0):

I've dug down into the macro and it looks like you have no control over the formatting to the populated value. Perhaps there's a more elegant solution, but at this point, you might try creating your own macro that gives you formatting control. (This is untested.)

```
<#macro numberInput path attributes="">
<@spring.bind path/>
<input type="text" 
       id="${status.expression?replace('[','')?replace(']','')}"
       name="${status.expression}" value="status.value?c" ${attributes}<@closeTag/>
</#macro>
```

You would call it like this:

```
<@numberInput 'CaseMaster.suitValue' 'placeholder="e.g. Suit Value" ' />
```